# How to optimize PRAW and pandas data collection to make it more pythonic?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, praw

I am using PRAW to get data from Reddit and created this function to do so on multiple subreddits.

It works, however, I am working on a more concise/pythonic version but can't figure out how I can create a single "for loop", doing the job of the 3 below.

```
subs = r.subreddit('Futurology+wallstreetbets+DataIsBeautiful+RenewableEnergy+Bitcoin')

#This function aim to scrap data from a list of subreddit.
#From these subreddit, I would like to get the #new, #hot and #rising posts

def get_data(size_new, size_hot, size_rising, subs_number):

posts = []
followers = []
targeted_date = '14-11-20 12:00:00'
targeted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(targeted_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')

#getting x new posts
for subreddit in subs.new(limit = size_new):
        date = subreddit.created
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
        if date >= targeted_date:
            posts.append([date, subreddit.subreddit, subreddit.title, subreddit.selftext])

#getting x hot posts
for subreddit in subs.hot(limit = size_hot):
    date = subreddit.created
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
    if date >= targeted_date:
        posts.append([date, subreddit.subreddit, subreddit.title, subreddit.selftext])

#getting x rising posts
for subreddit in subs.rising(limit = size_rising):
    date = subreddit.created
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
    if date >= targeted_date:
        posts.append([date, subreddit.subreddit, subreddit.title, subreddit.selftext])

#getting subreddit subscribers number
for sub_name in subs_2:
    for submission in r.subreddit(sub_name).hot(limit = 1):
        followers.append([submission.subreddit, r.subreddit(sub_name).subscribers])

#creating 2 df
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(followers, columns = ['subreddit','subscribers'])
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['date', 'subreddit', 'title', 'text']).drop_duplicates().sort_values(by = ['date']).reset_index(drop = True)


#concat the 2 df together
df = df.join(df_1.set_index('subreddit'), on = 'subreddit')
df = df[["date", "subreddit", "subscribers", "title", 'text']] 
df = df[df.subscribers > subs_number].reset_index(drop = True)

return df
```

**My request:** how could it be more concise/optimized? What methodology are you using to make your code more readable or even better, optimize it for run time/computational resources?

Thank you

Comment: There is "itertools.chain" to merge the three for-loops into one.

Comment: Ok thanks @MichaelButscher I will look into it :)

Answer (score 2):

There are various principles to make better code, and various tools to use to find the 'code smells' that may be lurking in your code.

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself

KISS - keep it stupid simple

SOLID

etc...

Taking a dive into the code that you posted using some of the principles on a surface level would refactor some of your code into looking like:

```
subs = r.subreddit('Futurology+wallstreetbets+DataIsBeautiful+RenewableEnergy+Bitcoin')

# check that the date is greater than the target date 
# return true/false
def check_date(subreddit, targeted_date):
    return subreddit.created >= targeted_date:

# get specific post data
def get_post_data(subreddit):
    return [subreddit.created, subreddit.subreddit, subreddit.title, subreddit.selftext]

# get posts by sort type
def get_subreddit_post_types(subreddit_sort, targeted_date):
    return [get_post_data(subreddit) for subreddit in subreddit_sort if check_date(subreddit, targeted_date)]

#This function aim to scrap data from a list of subreddit.
#From these subreddit, I would like to get the #new, #hot and #rising posts
def get_data(size_new, size_hot, size_rising, subs_number):
    targeted_date = '14-11-20 12:00:00'
    targeted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(targeted_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
    posts = []
    followers = []

    #getting x new posts
    posts.extend(get_subreddit_post_types(subs.new(limit = size_new), targeted_date))

    #getting x hot posts
    posts.extend(get_subreddit_post_types(subs.hot(limit = size_hot), targeted_date))

    #getting x rising posts
    posts.extend(get_subreddit_post_types(subs.rising(limit = size_rising), targeted_date))

    #getting subreddit subscribers number
    for sub_name in subs_2:
        for submission in r.subreddit(sub_name).hot(limit = 1):
            followers.append([submission.subreddit, r.subreddit(sub_name).subscribers])

    #creating 2 df
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(followers, columns = ['subreddit','subscribers'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['date', 'subreddit', 'title', 'text']).drop_duplicates().sort_values(by = ['date']).reset_index(drop = True)


    #concat the 2 df together
    df = df.join(df_1.set_index('subreddit'), on = 'subreddit')
    df = df[["date", "subreddit", "subscribers", "title", 'text']] 
    df = df[df.subscribers > subs_number].reset_index(drop = True)

    return df
```

As for better optimizing your computational resources (what are you trying to optimize memory or runtime)? The same process applies to either is to look at your code to see what can be changed to decrease one versus the other.

From looking at your code something that would generally optimize what you wrote would be to look at what are the 'duplicate' posts that you are getting. If you could remove the duplicate check (as each of the hot/rising/new get posts from similar date ranges, but hot/rising may be completely encompassed inside of new) call from the posts that you gathered, so that you don't have to check that they are different, and possibly remove hot/rising calls (because those posts may be encompassed in new).